# Spring XD project site documentation corrections

Tags: spring-xd

How can I submit documentation corrections to the [Spring XD project site](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/)?Is there a GitHub repository accepting pull-requests for these corrections?

Comment: Yes, it is. Feel free to raise GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/issues. And there you can find an info how to contribute: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Project-and-Community. And.. close this question, please, it isn't good for SO.

Comment: Thanks, @ArtemBilan - I've opened an issue, and generalized the question a bit to be more help, though it's still not a programming question, per se - so perhaps, as you suggest, this should be closed. Likely, though, others will have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring XD project site documentation are GitHub Pages maintained in the [`gh-pages` branch of the Spring XD GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/gh-pages); corrections can be submitted via normal pull-requests.

Comment: I've cloned the Wiki content but the content on the project site does not appear to part of the Wiki content...not sure where that content is being pulled in from. Perhaps Sagan is pulling the **Quick Start** section from somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry; I thought you meant the project documentation (which is currently generated from the wiki). I updated the answer.